# BootStrap "navbar-toggle" class will open, but not close

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a navbar that displays a button when the screen size is below a certain width; just as you've seen with many other Bootstrap sides. When the button is displayed and clicked, the navigation links display in a vertical dropdown, which works as intended.

The problem comes when I try to close the dropdown by re-clicking the link. No matter what I do it remains open. After inspecting the live site, it looks like the class 'in' is added on the first click, but not removed on subsequent clicks (the toggle function). I'm at a loss for how to correct this, as I believe my links are correct in the header. Does anyone have any experience with this problem?

EDIT: As clarification, I understand that I could write a workaround in my javascript document, but I don't want to go down that path if there is a more obvious solution.  Thanks for helping out a beginner.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/javascipt/main.js">  <!-- personal JS Script (Not Sure which is better) Icons -->
    <link href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">  <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
    <link href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet">  <!-- Personal CSS Stylesheet -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/javascript/main.js"></script>  <!-- Personal JS Script -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script> <!-- Bootstrap Script -->
<title><?echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

    <body>
    <div class="main contain">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse hold-top">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand nav-logo2" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'wpurl' ); ?>"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right header-text" id="myNavbar">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Services<span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Marketing Campaigns</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Donor Activation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lobbying</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">
    </span> Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in">
    </span> Login</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code Seems working fine ,The in class generated on click is a bootstrap class and after toogling it disapers .

What you can do put the external resourse js files such as jquery,bootstrap at first and then your custom js file at last ,may be something is conflicting between these js file thats why toogle function is not working

you can add the js reference file by maintaining the sequence like below

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
<link href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/javascipt/main.js"> 
<script src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/javascript/main.js">
```